# エラーの内容が理解できない：CustomControl - Button [修飾型名が無い為 メンバーは無効です]

Tags: c#, wpf

WPFでButtonをラップしたカスタムコントロールの作成を試しています。
今のところは以下2つの依存プロパティを定義したのみの簡単なものです。
①MouseOverBackground (マウスオーバー時のBrush)
②MouseDownBackground (マウスクリック時のBrush)

FlatButton.cs

```
    public class FlatButton : Button
    {
        static FlatButton()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FlatButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(FlatButton)));
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty MouseOverBackgroundProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "MouseOverBackground",
                typeof(Brush),
                typeof(FlatButton),
                new PropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkGray)));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty MouseDownBackgroundProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "MouseDownBackground",
                typeof(Brush),
                typeof(FlatButton),
                new PropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray)));


        public Brush MouseOverBackground
        {
            get => (Brush)GetValue(MouseOverBackgroundProperty);
            set => SetValue(MouseOverBackgroundProperty, value);
        }

        public Brush MouseDownBackground
        {
            get => (Brush)GetValue(MouseDownBackgroundProperty);
            set => SetValue(MouseDownBackgroundProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

Xamlの定義は以下のようになっています。
FlatButton.xaml

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:FlatButton}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:FlatButton}">
                    <Border x:Name="VisualBorder"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <Border.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="Border">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                            </Style>
                        </Border.Style>

                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="VisualBorder" Property="Background" Value="{TemplateBinding MouseOverBackground}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="VisualBorder" Property="Background" Value="{TemplateBinding MouseDownBackground}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

これでコンパイルを行ったところ、以下のエラーが発生しました。
[ 修飾型名がないため、'Background' メンバーは無効です。 ]

```
<Style TargetType="Border">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
</Style>
```

上の部分を削除するとコンパイルが通るのですが、エラーの内容が理解できません。
どの様に修正が必要かご教示お願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

エラーの意味は分からないのですが、`FlatButton.xaml`の`<Border ...>`と`</Border>`の間に`<Border.Style>...</Border.Style>`を定義しているのが問題なのでは？

その部分の初期値は以下のように既に`Background`は定義されているようです。

```
<Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">

</Border>
```

質問のソースに合わせて、以下のように`x:Name="VisualBorder"`と`<ContentPresenter.../>`を追加すればビルドは通るのではないでしょうか？

```
<Border x:Name="VisualBorder"
        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Border>
```

---

ちなみにこんな記事もあるようです。
[WPFのボタンをフラットデザインに変更する](https://takachan.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/12/27/000000)